# What is the meaning of 'live a little' and 'I am not feeling it anymore'?

Tags: meaning

I heard these 2 phrases from Netflix, but I did not find exact explanations of them.

Could anyone tell me how to use these phrases?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

"Live a little" means, "Enjoy your life a little more."  See:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live%20a%20little

For example, if someone works too hard or spends all their time taking care of other people, or if you feel they're too serious and are not enjoying their life, you might tell them, "Live a little!"

Without more context, it's hard to say what "I'm not feeling it any more" is referring to specifically, but the implication is that the speaker used to be excited about something or someone but is not feeling that excitement any more.  They could be referring to a person they used to love, a job they used to love, or anything else that used to make them feel joy or excitement but no longer does.

Both expressions are informal and would typically only be used in speech or written dialogue, or perhaps a personal letter.  The second expression might also occur in someone's journal or diary.